# C program, Stack Calculator

Tags: c, stack, calculator

Can someone please take a look at my code below and help me out. Ive been trying to fix this for hours but i cant figure out what's wrong. It's a program written in C that is supposed to take the operations of a stack calculator and store the operands of a mathematical expression. When an operation is performed, the last two values on the stack are removed and used as the operands, then the result of the operation is placed on the stack. However, I'm not getting the right numbers. Please take a look at my code. I know it's long, but I appreciate it. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 10
#define MAXINPUT 255


void printStack(int stack[], int tos)
{
if (isEmpty(tos))
{
    printf("Stack is empty\n");
    printf("---------------------------------------\n");
    return;
}   

printf("Stack: ");
while (tos < SIZE)
{
    printf("[%d] " , stack[tos]);
    tos++;

}   
printf("\n---------------------------------------\n");

}   


int top (int stack[], int tos)
{
if(isEmpty(tos))
    return;
return stack [tos];
}

int isEmpty(int tos)
{

if (tos < 0)
    return 1;
}

int isFull (int tos)
{

if(tos >= SIZE - 1)
    return 1;

}   

void push(int val, int stack [], int *tos)
{
if(isFull(*tos))
    return;
(*tos)++;
stack[*tos] = val;


}

int pop (int stack [], int *tos)
{

if(isEmpty(*tos))
    return;
int val = stack[*tos];
(*tos)--;
return val;
}

void clear(int *tos)
{
*tos = -1;

}   

int getInput (char *input)
{

printf("+------------------------------{Choose an option}------------------------------+\n");
printf("| (q) : quit the program.                                                      |\n"
       "| (integer value) : an integer value (either positive or negative) to push     |\n"
       "| (c) : clear the stack                                                        |\n"
       "| (=) : display top value on the stack                                         |\n"
       "| (+) : addition                                                               |\n"
       "| (-) : subtraction                                                            |\n"
       "| (*) : multiplication                                                         |\n"
       "| (/) : division - integer division only                                       |\n"
       "| (%) : modulus - remainder from an integer division                           |\n"
       "| (^) : exponentiation (x raised to the power of y)                            |\n"
       "+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
printf("Input: ");
gets(input);
if(strcmp(input, "q") == 0)
{
    printf("Exiting...\n");
    return 0;
}
return 1;
}   

int isNum(char *input)
{
int i;
for(i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++)
{
    if(!isdigit(input[i]))
        return 0;
}   
return 1;

}   

int hasTwo(tos)
{
if((SIZE - tos) >= 2)
    return 1;

printf("\nStack size is 1, must have 2 or more\n");
return 0;
}
void mathOp (char op, int stack[], int *tos)
{
if(!isEmpty(*tos))
    return;
if(!hasTwo(*tos))
    return;

int right = pop(stack, tos);
int left = pop(stack, tos); 
switch(op)
{
    case '+': 
        push((left + right), stack, tos);
        break;
    case '-': 
        push((left - right), stack, tos);
        break;
    case '*': 
        push((left * right), stack, tos);
        break;
    case '/': 
        push((left/right), stack, tos);
        break;
    case '%': 
        push((left % right), stack, tos);
        break;
    case '^': 
        push(pow(left, right), stack, tos);
        break;
}       

}   

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int verbose = 0;
int debugMode = 0;
if (argc == 2 && argv[1][0] == '-' && argv[1][1] == 'd')
{   
    debugMode = 1;
    if (strcmp("-dv", argv[1]) == 0)
    {
        verbose = 1;
    }
}

int stack[SIZE];
int tos = -1;
char input[MAXINPUT];
while (getInput(input))
{
    int result = 0;
    if (strcmp(input, "c") == 0)
        clear(&tos);
    else if (strcmp(input, "=") == 0)
    {

        result = top(stack, tos);
        printf("Top of Stack is [%d]\n", result);
    }
    else if (isNum(input))
        push(atoi(input), stack, &tos);
    else if(strcmp(input, "+") == 0 ||
            strcmp(input, "-") == 0 ||
            strcmp(input, "*") == 0 ||
            strcmp(input, "/") == 0 ||          
            strcmp(input, "%") == 0 ||          
            strcmp(input, "^") == 0 ) mathOp(input[0], stack, &tos);
    else
        printf("Invalid input\n");

    if (debugMode)
        printStack(stack, tos);     
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Give us more context. What are you putting into it? What are you getting out? What are you expecting? That'll help narrow things down.

Comment: +1 @TheCapn.  Also, you might want to try a debugger - you'll probably find your problem in moments.

Comment: I'm just trying to allow the user to enter two integers. When the user enters the first integer, it gets pushed onto the stack, and then when the user enters the next integer, it also gets pushed onto the stack. Then, when a user picks an operation, the top two values are popped off, an operation is performed with those two, then the result is pushed onto the stack. And the order of the operands is important. The first value taken off the stack is the right-hand-side operand, while the second value taken off the stack is the left-hand-side operand.

Comment: Don't use `gets()` — it is too dangerous.  Forget it exists.  Pretend it will cause your machine to melt into a puddle of molten silicon and metal (and carbonized plastic).  There is simply no way to use it reliably.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of problems in this code. Compile with `-Wall` (or equivalent setting) to find that `isEmpty` and `isFull` and `top` and `pop` don't (always) properly return a value.

Every function that needs to return something, must end in a return statement. There is no 'default return value' of some sorts in C.

So as an example:

```
int isFull (int tos)
{
    if(tos >= SIZE - 1)
        return 1;

    return 0; // <-- not full, you probably want to return 0
}
```

ps. You need to use `%%` for a literal `%` in the help text.

**edit** to fix everything:

1. `printStack` is badly broken, you need to loop from `0` to `tos`, not from `tos` to `SIZE`.
2. `hasTwo` needs to test if `tos>=1`.
3. `mathOp` needs to test first `if(isEmpty(*tos))`, remove the `!` which says not "if not empty".

Then it should work.

Comment: but the top and pop functions do end in a return statement

Comment: yes, but they return nothing, whereas you specify they are returning an `int`. The compiler warns about this. Chances are it doesn't return `0` if you simply say `return;`

Comment: mvds thanks for the help. sorry for the late response. but I'm still trying to get the hang of C programming. I have a couple questions. I have a couple of questions still. I tried doing what you said for the printStack function and loop from 0 to tos instead of tos to SIZE. However, when I do that, I get a segmentation fault. When I leave it the other way, from tos to SIZE, it's not right, but it works "somewhat".

Comment: Also, I incorporated the second and third changes u told me to do, and the program works fine if I don't run it in debug mode though. However, how is that the case if the top and pop functions don't return proper integer values? Can you explain this to me and try to break it down if possible? I'm still having a hard time understand the concept. I don't see what's wrong with two functions. Both the top and pop functions are supposed to return integer values, and to me, they do. In the _top_ function, it says __return stack [tos];__. and in the _pop_ function, it says __return val;__. theyreint.

Comment: @MikeSmith: you should also remove the `tos++` line in the `printStack` routine, maybe that's biting you. Furthermore, programming (especially C) is more like math than, say, painting; "works somewhat" mostly means "doesn't really work". Compare math: e.g. 2*125 just does not really equal 251. Sometimes things work somewhat, by accident. Don't count on it. If the compiler issues a warning, fix it. Or switch to a language like PHP which allows for (very) sloppy programming.

Comment: @MikeSmith the `top()` function does a `return;` with no arguments, if the stack is empty. However, you stated it should (always!) return an int. So you must make it return an int, **always**. Otherwise, you return a garbage value. Especially `isEmpty` is a problem, because there is *no* return statement if the stack is *not* empty. The probability of it returning non-zero is high, so your stack will appear empty often.

Comment: @MikeSmith you should be able to fix it all yourself, but if you have further questions, please edit the question with your updated code, for clarity. I'm off now, so don't expect a quick response from me.